# addClass on div you are hovering over when other divs have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addclass

I have an issue where I want to add a class to one of the section divs below on hover:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

This code adds the class to them all, how can I make it just the one you are hovering over? I read up on jquery .next but couldn't get it to work either. NOTE: the section divs are from a loop and are all the same class name, I cannot change this.

jQuery is:

```
jQuery(".container .section").hover(
  function() {
    jQuery(".section").addClass("selected");
  },
  function() {
    jQuery(".section").removeClass("selected");
  }
);
```

Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/8juoy2vz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, (`$(this)` refers to current element, in our case it will be one of the `.section`)

```
jQuery(".container .section").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8juoy2vz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery(".section")`:

```
jQuery(".container .section").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

```js
jQuery(".container .section").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">Stuff</div>
    <div class="section">Stuff</div>
    <div class="section">Stuff</div>
    <div class="section">Stuff</div>
    <div class="section">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

`jQuery(".section")` selects all elements that have the class section, while `jQuery(this)` refers to only the element that's being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it all in CSS?

You could have something like this:

```
.section:hover {
  // Whatever you had in the .selected class
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8juoy2vz/3/

Comment: I could but I intend to maybe do some other jQuery stuff alongside the class change. Thanks anyway.